# Unhandled Promise rejection: expression.split is not a function when using Splitter

Tags: angular, onsen-ui

I have an error when using the **ons-splitter**. I already asked the question in OnsenUI's forum but I might as well ask it here...

Here is the complete details of my question:

https://community.onsen.io/topic/3371/unhandled-promise-rejection-expression-split-is-not-a-function-when-using-splitter

Thanks!